# Odoo 10: button to trigger function in related model

Tags: odoo-10, odoo-view

I can't find any example of how to trigger a function of a related model in a view.
Here's my code:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    _name = 'trip'
    _description = 'Trip'
    destinations = fields.One2many('destination', 'trip_id', string='destinations')

class Destination(models.Model):
    _name = 'destination'
    _description = 'Trip'
    trip_id = fields.Many2one('trip', 'Trip')

    def generate_doc:
        # code to generate report
```

Basically there are 2 models (trip and destination) with a One2many relation. Here's my view code:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="trip_form">
    <field name="name">trip.form</field>
    <field name="model">trip</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="destinations" readonly="True">
        <tree>
          <button name="generate_doc" type="object" string="DOC"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
```

What I am trying to do here is executing a method inside the related model (destination) from a view of the main model (trip). Problem is my code executes the method inside the main model (trip) and not inside the related model (destination). I understand that it is possible to pass some Context to a button... but how to do it? I can't find any working example of it!
Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 0):

My bad! The code is working correctly, and the button is calling the method inside the right model!